# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark and Kafka, learning them now. I am trying to integrate Kafka with Spark, I was successful in executing the program through eclipse. 
When I tried with Spark Submit I am getting below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer

My build content:

```
name := "spark_streaming"
version := "0.0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.1" % "provided",
"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.11.0.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.11.0.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-assembly" % "1.5.2"
)
```

Comment: Could you please run the "jar tvf <path-to-jar-file>" command and inspect the contents of the package and see if the Consumer class is available or not? I ran into a similar problem and my jar file turned out to be corrupt.

Comment: I am not able to find this package inside the jar file. I was able to see the class in dependency jars. May I know how you solved this problem? Thank you.

Comment: In my case, I found out that the jar was corrupt because the "jar tvf <path-to-jar-file>" didn't work. So, I just rebuilt the jar and then i could see the class that was originally missing (NoClassDefFoundError). After this, my program worked.